# Authenticating users with ldap in Django project

Tags: python, django, ldap

I am trying to authenticate users against my ldap server.

I have successfully ran pip install python-ldap and django-auth-ldap..

I am running python 2.7..

Every time I try to login my to Django admin with my superuser account I get the following error:

```
AttributeError at /admin/login/
'module' object has no attribute 'LDAPError'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/
Django Version: 1.11.9
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'module' object has no attribute 'LDAPError'
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_auth_ldap\backend.py in authenticate, line 384
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.13
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\donallane\\Desktop\\My_Django_Stuff\\ldap-login\\learning_users',
 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\python_ldap-2.4.10-py2.7-win32.egg']
Server time:    Thu, 8 Feb 2018 16:59:10 +0000
```

ldap configurations in settings.py:

```
####### ---------------  LDAP Configuration ------------ #######
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, GroupOfNamesType

# AUTH_LDAP_START_TLS = True
# AUTH_LDAP_GLOBAL_OPTIONS = {
#     #ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT: False,
#     #ldap.OPT_REFERRALS: False,
# }
#
# AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldaps://ldap.ecf.orca.ie"
# AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = 'cn=myapp,ou=apps,o=company'
# AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = 'myapp_password'
# AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=people,o=company", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s)")
#
# AUTH_LDAP_ALWAYS_UPDATE_USER = False
# #
# AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
#     "first_name": "givenName",
#     "last_name": "sn",
#     "email": "mail"
# }

# import ldap
#
# AUTH_LDAP_CONNECTION_OPTIONS = {
#     ldap.OPT_REFERRALS: 0
# }

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

auth_connection.py:

```
import ldap
# try this code and catch the ldap error
try:
    l = ldap.initialize("ldap://ldap.ecf.orca.ie")
    out = l.simple_bind_s("uid=username,ou=people,o=company", "password")

    print out
    exit()
# any errors will throw an LDAP error exception
# or related exception so you can ignore the result
except ldap.LDAPError as e:
    print e
```

Output of pip freeze:

```
Django==1.11.9
django-auth-ldap==1.3.0
django-filter==1.1.0
djangorestframework==3.7.7
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
httplib2==0.10.3
ldap==1.0.2
ldap3==2.4.1
Markdown==2.6.11
oauth2==1.9.0.post1
psycopg2==2.7.3.2
pyasn1==0.4.2
PyJWT==1.5.3
python-ldap==2.4.10
python-oauth2==1.0.1
pytz==2017.3
```

Comment: You should post the output of `pip freeze`.

Comment: Hi I have this added above

Comment: I'm not sure where `ldap.LDAPError` is defined.  When I load your environment from the contents of your `pip freeze` command and do `from ldap import LDAPError` I get `ImportError: cannot import name LDAPError` so I think you may be seeing library incompatibilities and you're in ["dependency hell"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell).  This is what I used for my LDAP authentication when I started way back https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/901/ .  That is still working for me, so maybe you should try out that route instead of `django_auth_ldap`.

Comment: I have indeed landed in Dependency Hell man. I will try this snippet in the morning thanks for sharing it!

Comment: @RossRogers I have a question about this snippet. Its giving me an error when I navigate to the Admin login its an ImportError telling me there is no module named 'reviewboard.accounts.backends'. I can see this is part of the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS (.... etc ) is there a way around this? I tried pip install some review board module, it took away the error but then uninstalled my version of Django and reinstalled an older one that would not support my url modules..

Comment: The snippet isn't drop-in ready.  You need to change `reviewboard.accounts.backends` to `your_foo_project.your_bar_app.backends`.  `reviewboard` was this lady's top django project name.

Comment: Perfect thanks I got it working!

Comment: [See my comment at the bottom of that snippet.](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/901/)  You need to tweak the snippet so you don't set everyone's password to `'ldap authenticated`'.  Search for `user.set_password` in the  the comments.